# LEFT JOIN Perfomance issue mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This query works fine and brings 598 rows:

```
SELECT pdwspend.`Parent Supplier Name` , pdwspend.`Child Supplier ID` , pdwspend.`Cat     Tree - Cate` , sum( pdwspend.`Spend Value in LC` )
FROM pdwspend
WHERE pdwspend.Version = 'FINAL'
AND pdwspend.YearMonth >= '201310'
AND pdwspend.YearMonth <= '201409'
AND pdwspend.`Excludable` != 'Excluded'
AND pdwspend.`Year` = '2014'
AND pdwspend.`BU ID` = 'BU1'
GROUP BY pdwspend.`Parent Supplier Name`
```

I want to bring ALL EXCEPT when pdwspend.`Child Supplier ID` = scrubs.`BW Parent Number`. There should be around 70 matches, therefore, the query should bring around 528 rows.This is the query that I have:

```
SELECT pdwspend.`Parent Supplier Name` , pdwspend.`Child Supplier ID` , pdwspend.`Cat Tree - Cate` , sum( pdwspend.`Spend Value in LC` ) 
FROM pdwspend
LEFT JOIN scrubs ON  pdwspend.`Child Supplier ID`  = scrubs.`BW Parent Number`
WHERE pdwspend.Version = 'FINAL'
AND pdwspend.YearMonth >= '201310'
AND pdwspend.YearMonth <= '201409'
AND pdwspend.`Excludable` != 'Excluded'
AND pdwspend.`Year` = '2014'
AND pdwspend.`BU ID` = 'BU1'
AND scrubs.`BW Parent Number` IS NULL 
GROUP BY pdwspend.`Parent Supplier Name`
```

But mySQL freezes after running it.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `not exists`:

```
SELECT s.`Parent Supplier Name` , s.`Child Supplier ID` , s.`Cat     Tree - Cate` ,
       sum(s.`Spend Value in LC` )
FROM pdwspend s
WHERE s.Version = 'FINAL' AND s.YearMonth >= '201310' AND s.YearMonth <= '201409' AND
      s.`Excludable` <> 'Excluded' AND s.`Year` = '2014' AND s.`BU ID` = 'BU1' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM scrubs sc
                  WHERE s.`Child Supplier ID` = sc.`BW Parent Number`
                 )
GROUP BY s.`Parent Supplier Name` ;
```

For performance, you want an index on `scrubs(BW Parent Number)`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the report still freezes. The scrubs table has more columns than `BW Parent Number`. I tried this without success:                                                                      
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT sc.`BW Parent Number`
                  FROM scrubs sc
                  WHERE s.`Child Supplier ID` = sc.`BW Parent Number` AND    sc.`Year` = '2014'
                 )

Comment: @nangys . . . This should be adding one more lookup to your original query, one that uses an index.  It is hard to see how this would "freeze" MySQL when the other returns quickly.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this issue by changing the position of the the table since I think is more efficient. This is what I came up with. It brings error #1054 becuase of the filed `Spend Value in LC`. Is it because of the `Spend Value in LC` is not in the FROM clause? How can I change it? Thanks again:

Comment: SELECT sc.`BW Parent Number`, sum(b.`Spend Value in LC`)
FROM scrubs sc
WHERE sc.`year` =2014 
AND NOT EXISTS (

     SELECT 1
     FROM pdwspend AS b
     WHERE version LIKE '%FINAL%'
     AND b.`Child Supplier ID` = sc.`BW Parent Number`
     )
GROUP BY sc.`BW Parent Number`

Comment: You can't aggregate by a column in a subquery in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should use inner join if you want to view only Child Supplier ID = scrubs.BW Parent Number

```
SELECT pdwspend.`Parent Supplier Name` , pdwspend.`Child Supplier ID` , pdwspend.`Cat Tree     - Cate` , sum( pdwspend.`Spend Value in LC` ) 
FROM pdwspend
INNER JOIN scrubs ON  pdwspend.`Child Supplier ID`  = scrubs.`BW Parent Number`
WHERE pdwspend.Version = 'FINAL'
AND pdwspend.YearMonth >= '201310'
AND pdwspend.YearMonth <= '201409'
AND pdwspend.`Excludable` != 'Excluded'
AND pdwspend.`Year` = '2014'
AND pdwspend.`BU ID` = 'BU1'
AND scrubs.`BW Parent Number` IS NULL 
GROUP BY pdwspend.`Parent Supplier Name`
```

OR you can try SUBQUERY USE INDEX FOR `Child Supplier ID` AND  scrubs.`BW Parent Number` 
for great performance .